# Show n-1 is a natural number

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, induction

Show that $n \in N, n>0 \Rightarrow n-1 \in N$. We can use the basic axioms and we also know that $N$ is the smallest possible set $A$, where $A$ meets the following criteria:
1) $0 \in A$ 2) $\forall x \in R: x \in A \Rightarrow x+1 \in A$. My reasoning is the following. We can choose $A= \ldots \cup \{-1\} \cup \{0\} \cup \{1\} \cup \ldots$ to satisfy both conditions. We notice that $x \in A \Rightarrow x-1 \in A$. Since $N \subset A$, we have $n-1 \in N$. Is this correct? Additionally, do we have an induction proof for this?

Comment: $A$ (including $-1$) is not the *smallest* set satisfying those criteria, so you cannot use its construction as a demonstration of the proposition.  (ETA: It is also not the case that $x \in A \Rightarrow x-1 \in A$, since $-1 \in A$ but $-2 \not\in A$.)

Comment: I was not stating that my specific $A$ was the smallest possible set, just that it was a set satisfying those criteria. In general it is $N$ that's the smallest possible set satisfying the criteria and I'm trying to use the fact that $N \subset A$. Also, both $-1$ and $-2$ are in my specific $A$ which is a set of all integers. Hope this clarifies my question a bit.

Comment: Ahh, I missed the meaning of the leading ellipses.  I still don't think your reasoning is sound, because you can't reason from the conditional inclusion in the larger set (namely, $\mathbb{Z}$) to conclude the conditional inclusion in its subset $\mathbb{N}$.  For instance, if you remove the $>0$ condition, the proposition is true for $\mathbb{Z}$ but not for $\mathbb{N}$.  Therefore, your argument must in some way use the $>0$ condition.